# OpenGL ES 2 issue in android device

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am a beginner to OpenGl in Android and trying to make a Triange as you can see below thw class Triangle. The issue is that when I am just trying to draw a simple triangle the code runs on my device but when I apply the Projection and Camera Transformations through matrix then the application just crashes. I am testing the app on Samsun Galaxy Grand which has "Broadcom VideoCore IV" as its GPU which supports OpenGL ES 2.0 then why is the application crashing? Is it the code of the Triangle class or the Renderer or the device Graphics Processing Unit of the device??? (Below are given classes of Triangle and The Renderer)

Triangle Class  :

```
class Triangle {

    int mProgram;

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    float triangleCoords[] = { // in counterclockwise order:
         0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f,   // top
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
         0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f    // bottom right
    };

    private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    // Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;   \n" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;  \n" +
            "void main() {  \n" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;    \n" +
            "}  \n";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";


    public Triangle() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                triangleCoords.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables



    }

    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL ES environment

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        int mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }

    public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }
}
```

}

Renderer Class :

```
    public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    Triangle mTriangle;
    float ratio;
    int width,height;
    float[] mProjMatrix=new float[16];
    float[] mVMatrix=new float[16];
    float[] mMVPMatrix=new float[16];

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // mTriangle=new Triangle();

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

        // Draw shape
        mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);

    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: crashing means when I run the app in the device. It shows a note that " Unfortunaltely, <Appname> has stopped."

Comment: In emulator it is just saying that " No cofigs match configspecs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message usually means that the EGL driver can not find support for the required surface type for OpenGL ES rendering, which is typically GL_RGBA.  You probably don't have OpenGL ES support enabled for your AVD emulator.  This guide will help with that:

```
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1
```

Also, I highly recommend starting your OpenGL ES development with a good sample program.  This guide also helps with that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You still did not clarify where exactly the crash occurs...

But here what I´ve found:

In *onDrawFrame* you try to draw the triangle which actually does not exist (typical cause for crashes):

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
...
// Draw shape
mTriangle.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}
```

You have to initialize the triangle in *onSurfaceCreated* first:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
...
// initialize a triangle
mTriangle = new Triangle();
```

}

Please refer to this Android Training article:

[Displaying Graphics with OpenGL ES > Initialize Shapes](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html#initialize)

Comment: So should I try with only projection matrix.??

Answer (score 0):

Initially i too faced the same problem, My problem is similar, I can say that exactly if i had your MyGLSurfaceView class in MainActivity.java
**i have added super.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); before  setRenderer(mRenderer);** that solved my problem.

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
    super(context);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

    super.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
}
```

Hope even you got the same problem